# How to use generic list in sql merge Statement

Tags: c#, sql

I have used SQL merge Statement Which contain source table as Sql User Defined Table Type.

I have passed C# datatable as User Defined Table type. It works fine as per our requirements.I would like to know how to pass Generic List as User Defined Table for All Merge Statement.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more.  A SQL MERGE statement is very definitely a SQL thing - it has nothing to do with C# or with System.Data.DataTable.  Can you show us your code that is working and better describe how you want to genercize it?

Comment: You can use LINQ to select `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` but you will need to know your table type definition upfront. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done, because a user defined table type in SQL server has to be mapped out to a model(class) in C# which exactly mirrors it. There is no way to genericise the process between .Net and SQL Server to pass an unknown type as a list.

---

##### Merge a user defined table type

1. Define your `user defined table type` in the database.
2. Test it by loading as such

```
   DECLARE @budgetTT as dto.PublishedBudgetData

    insert into @budgetTT    
    select 666, 'FacNumber1', 'FacName1', 'CostCenterNumber1',  'CostCenterName1',  'UOSDESC #1', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.1, '1-Jan-2020' union all 
    select 666, 'FacNumber3', 'FacName3', 'CostCenterNumber3', 'CostCenterName3', 'UOSDESC #2', 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.9, '1-Jan-2020' 

select * from @budgetTT
```

1. Merge into a Table and define names like `Target` (the table where data will be inserted, updated, or deleted, and `Source` which is the user defined table type data.

```sql
MERGE dbo.Budget AS TARGET
USING @budgetTT AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.FacilityName     = SOURCE.FacilityName
AND TARGET.CostCenterNumber = SOURCE.CostCenterNumber
AND TARGET.CostCenterName   = SOURCE.CostCenterName 
AND TARGET.EngagementId     = SOURCE.EngagementId
AND TARGET.UOSDescription   = SOURCE.UOSDescription
AND TARGET.[Year]           = SOURCE.[Year])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
                -- TARGET.CostCenterName       = SOURCE.CostCenterName,
                -- TARGET.FacilityName         = SOURCE.FacilityName,
                -- TARGET.EngagementId         = SOURCE.EngagementId,
                -- TARGET.CostCenterNumber     = SOURCE.CostCenterNumber,
                TARGET.FacilityNumber          = SOURCE.FacilityNumber,
                TARGET.BudgetedVolumeForUOS    = SOURCE.BudgetedVolumeForUOS,
                TARGET.BudgetedTotalWorkedFTEs = SOURCE.BudgetedTotalWorkedFTEs,
                TARGET.BudgetedTotalPaidFTEs   = SOURCE.BudgetedTotalPaidFTEs,
                TARGET.WHPUOS                  = SOURCE.WHPUOS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (FacilityName, CostCenterNumber, CostCenterName, EngagementId, UOSDescription, [Year], FacilityNumber, BudgetedVolumeForUOS, BudgetedTotalWorkedFTEs, BudgetedTotalPaidFTEs, WHPUOS)
    VALUES (SOURCE.FacilityName, 
            SOURCE.CostCenterNumber,
            SOURCE.CostCenterName,
            SOURCE.EngagementId,
            SOURCE.UOSDescription,
            SOURCE.[Year],
            SOURCE.FacilityNumber,
            SOURCE.BudgetedVolumeForUOS,
            SOURCE.BudgetedTotalWorkedFTEs,
            SOURCE.BudgetedTotalPaidFTEs,
            SOURCE.WHPUOS);
```

Comment: OK noted, How to use bulk insert or update using generic list without using loop??

Comment: To be clear, as long as your ado code can scan each object in the list and push it appropriately to the sproc as a the user table type, it can sit in a generic list per-se.

Comment: So one has a list in C#, the code changes the list a sql server call as TableTypeRows and with the defined table type specified, then the sproc on the other end takes a read-only table of the user defined table type and does the `Merge` of that table within it.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan can you show the query that you use for merging a List<T> that is mapped to a table?

Comment: The above gives you a starting point for doing what you need to do.